# Why don't compilers convert int[][] to int** which is theoretically possible?

Tags: c

In C, two dimensional arrays are stored in the way just like linear arrays, but they are indexed using a double pointer. That is, if we define

```
int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}.
```

`a` first points to something like

```
{p1 = 0x7fff5fbffb58 , p2 = 0x7fff5fbffb70, p3 = 0x7fff5fbffb88}
```

then `p1` points to 1, `p2` points to 4 and `p3` points to 7.

So why don't compilers allow for a conversion from the two dimensional array to the double pointer which is theoretically possible? Although 2-D arrays are stored one by one, but the index information can always be passed to an arbitrary double pointer.

Comment: For a 2D array, the compiler does not store the intermediate pointers, your hypothetical `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.

Comment: -1 for false assumption. It's not theoretically possible. **Arrays are not pointers!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not theoretically possible. 2d arrays are not indexed using a double pointer - the compiler convert it to one index. For example, if you have `int a[3][5]`, and you access `a[i][j]`, the compiler convert it to `((int[])a)[5*i+j]`. (Your explanation is completely wrong)

Because of all of that, if you want to convert `int[][]` to `int**`, you need to allocate memory to save the addresses of all the sub-arrays, and get the address of it. Just `(int**)a` will not work.

Comment: I see! So things like double (*y)[3] = a actually does a conversion from a 2-D array to a list full of pointers!

Comment: no. it "convert" it to pointer to array. since you can access pointer like an array, you can access y like 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

Your example illustrates the reason why compilers cannot do it: the values of `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` are *calculated*, not stored. The compiler knows the address of `p1`, and calculates the other two with the knowledge of the array size in hand. With double pointers, on the other hand, all three pointers would need to be *stored* in sequential memory locations, forming an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Converting `int[][]` to `int**` would require introducing array of `int` pointers full of data. We love `c` for not taking such liberties when not explicitly asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Because C says so.

> (C99, 6.3.2.1p3) "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & 
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."

This conversion rule is not recursive for array of array.

The value of an object of type `int [N][M]` is of type `int (*)[M]` after conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Because are two different things. *int a[3][3]*, in the memory is an *array* of 9 elements.
*int*** you should have an array of pointers with 3 elements that each one of them will point to another array, that will contains the data.